# MySql query not giving proper data with LIMIT 3

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query to fetch data. I am seeing some insonsistency in data fetched and the Dish 'Gaja' seems to be repeated when I use LIMIT 3 only. It works fine for other LIMITS. Below is the query with all data without any LIMIT and OFFSET.

```
select DishName, ServingDateFrom, ServingDateTo, ServingTimeFrom, ServingTimeTo , d.DateCreated , d.DateUpdated 
from bv.sellerdishstatus sds 
INNER JOIN bv.dish d 
where sds.DishId=d.DishId AND 
sds.SellerId IN (232,234,443,564) AND 
sds.DishStatus IN (7,8) AND 
d.servingDateTo <= ('2024-03-14') 
ORDER BY d.ServingDateFrom ASC
```

[image: Query with all data]

```
select DishName, ServingDateFrom, ServingDateTo, ServingTimeFrom, ServingTimeTo , d.DateCreated , d.DateUpdated 
from bv.sellerdishstatus sds 
INNER JOIN bv.dish d 
where sds.DishId=d.DishId AND 
sds.SellerId IN (232,234,443,564) AND 
sds.DishStatus IN (7,8) AND 
d.servingDateTo <= ('2024-03-14') 
ORDER BY d.ServingDateFrom ASC 
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

So above query with LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0 gives me below data where I am not sure how Dish 'Gaja' is added as 3rd item. I was expecting 'Piece', 'Chicken Biryani' and '**Samosa**' instaed.
[image: First query LIMIT 3 with OFFSET 3]

```
select DishName, ServingDateFrom, ServingDateTo, ServingTimeFrom, ServingTimeTo , d.DateCreated , d.DateUpdated 
from bv.sellerdishstatus sds 
INNER JOIN bv.dish d 
where sds.DishId=d.DishId AND 
sds.SellerId IN (232,234,443,564) AND 
sds.DishStatus IN (7,8) AND 
d.servingDateTo <= ('2024-03-14') 
ORDER BY d.ServingDateFrom ASC 
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

And above query with LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3 gives me below correct data where I have 'Cutlet', 'Gaja' and 'Jalebi'
[image: Second query LIMIT 3 with OFFSET 3]

Any clue will be helpful because when I execute the query with LIMIT 4 or LIMIT 2 etc, it just works

Comment: Samosa and Gaja share the same ServingDateFrom. I.e. both are correct.

Comment: @jarlh So why did it pick up Gaja and not Cutlet(it also has same ServingDateFrom)?

Comment: Because of limit 3  it can only return 3 rows.

Comment: Do ask why Gaja was chosen instead of Cutlet? I don't know the MySQL internals, so I can't answer that question. However, what's important to remember as an SQL _user_  is that the result might change if there's no 100% defined order without ties.